# How many *ways* do we have to choose a matrix representation of a group?

Tags: representation-theory

Reading about the following example,

[image]

I'm wondering if there's a quick way of identifying which matrices are related to elements of the group I'm representing.

Here, for example I would have expected the map

$$\rho_{(12)}:\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$$

to be represented b the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$, namely exchanging the two columns.

Why in the above example the action looks like that? In particular, how many *ways* do we have to *choose* a matrix representation?

So based on my understanding all we would need to provide here is that $\rho_{(12)} \circ \rho_{(12)} = I_{\mathbb{C}^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $\phi: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a representation and $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is any matrix, then the map $\phi^A: G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ by $\phi^A(g) = A\phi(g)A^{-1}$ is also a representation.

Recall from linear algebra that we only get a matrix to represent a linear map once we have picked bases for the spaces. So conjugating a representation by a matrix this way just means we have the same action of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ but we are picking a different basis to write our matrix in. This is what motivates the notion of "isomorphic" representations.

Anyway the matrix you wrote is conjugate to the one in the example, so you can extend it to a representation just by conjugating the other elements by the same thing.